# tomcat equivalent of -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs in jboss

Tags: tomcat, jboss, jvm-arguments

I am trying to use an eclipse plugin called Jidebug. For this plugin to run on a jboss server, the VM argument "-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs" to server launch. Can anyone tell me what arguments to use if it has to run on tomcat?

below is a link to jidebug documentation.

http://4dsoft.eu/jidebug/use/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use this VM argument when running Tomcat, only in case of JBoss.